# Is it possible to create calculation rows from query results in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a way to output a calculation row (or two) of an SQL search query, so I may see the raw results along with a calculation associated to them, either above or under the listing of raw results. For instance, I have the following data:

```
mysql> select * from data [where condition];
+----+--------+-----+--------+
| id | height | age | weight |
+----+--------+-----+--------+
|  1 |   65.2 |  45 |  45.23 |
|  2 |   63.1 |  47 |      0 |
|  3 |   59.2 |  37 |   38.1 |
|  4 |   59.8 |  39 |   36.4 |
|  5 |   63.4 |  37 |   38.1 |
|  6 |   72.1 |  34 |      2 |
|  7 |    100 |  50 |     20 |
+----+--------+-----+--------+
```

And what I want is to be able to perform any query to get all or a subset of this data, but have the resulting table give something like the following (with the summary/calculation output separate from the raw data, such as either above or below it):

```
mysql> query???
+--------+--------+------+--------+
|   id   | height |  age | weight |
+--------+--------+------+--------+
|      1 |   65.2 |   45 |  45.23 |
|      2 |   63.1 |   47 |      0 |
|      3 |   59.2 |   37 |   38.1 |
|      4 |   59.8 |   39 |   36.4 |
|      5 |   63.4 |   37 |   38.1 |
|      6 |   72.1 |   34 |      2 |
|      7 |    100 |   50 |     20 |
+--------+--------+------+--------+
| STDDEV |  13.26 | 5.57 |  17.15 |
|  COUNT |      7 |    7 |      7 |
|   etc. |   etc. | etc. |   etc. |
+--------+--------+------+--------+
```

I've found some approaches such as this (http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/06/sql-server-row-summary-column-summary.html) that somewhat do it, but because the calculation acts on all rows it doesn't work well for some calculations (for instance, using stddev results in "0" for everything except the calculation row).

I can create a separate result of calculations such as the following, but it would be nice to have them somehow combined, such as shown above. In addition, the following only outputs one row of calculations, and it would be nice to have several rows of pertinent calculations.

```
select stddev(height), stddev(age), stddev(weight) from data [where condition];
```

The point here is to perform any search query and get an auto-generated preview of basic descriptive information from the results (deviations, counts, mean, etc.). Hopefully this can be done directly in SQL, without needing to use another language/API.

Comment: What you can do is add columns stddev_age, stddev_weight and so on to your query, will be the same for each row, so if you look at any row from the result you can get this info if you want to. Might by ugly, but no conflict with datatypes and pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 3):

Combine your results with `union`. If you need the results in a particular order, then create a column containing the precedence and order by that column.

```
select id, height, age, weight, 0 sortorder 
from data [where condition]
union all
select 'stdev count', stddev(height), stddev(age), stddev(weight), 1
from data [where condition]
order by sortorder
```

Comment: Note that this only works if both queries in the union must have the same number of columns and the columns should share data types.  MySQL might do some silent data conversion if they don't match, but then it might decide to do something like truncate `stddev(age)` to an integer, or your app might get confused when the id column is suddenly a string instead of an int.  Honestly, it seems significantly less usable than a second query.

Comment: @BaconBits Agreed. If it's possible, then 2 queries might be the better approach.

Comment: Ah ok...the union operation works to get the table formatted, though it is a bit cumbersome as it requires you apply the desired conditions for each query being unioned. Is there a way to specify the query and its conditions only once and then have the calculations act upon the returned data from that initial query?

Comment: @Topher you could create a view containing your where condition but it would still be separate processes. I think you're looking for something like `WITH ROLLUP` but for other functions. Unfortunately that doesn't exist.

Comment: @FuzzyTree, a separate view seems helpful, but it seems to require setting the condition upon creation, which then can't be updated later on. This makes the view somewhat static. I want to be able to set a query condition, and then have the summary view update dynamically. For instance, if I limit the query to the first 3 results, then I'd like to have the view show a count of 3, along with STDDEV and other calculations just on those three. As-is, if the view were created with the condition "limit 7" then it will always show the calculations from 7 results, and not update to act on the query.